# "No route matches the supplied values" once again

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm using ASP.NET Core 3 Web API. When trying to set the location header for a created entity using `CreatedAtAction`, it fails with `System.InvalidOperationException: No route matches the supplied values.` All the answers I found so far on SO didn't solve my issue  So I really hope somebody can help me.

Here is my controller:

```cs
[ApiVersion("1.0")]
[Route(ApiVersionSegment + "/<<domain-specific resource name>>/")]
public class DomainController : BaseApiController
{
    private const string ReportsSegment = "reports";

    [HttpGet(ReportsSegment + "/{reportId}")]
    public ActionResult<ReportModel> GetReport(int reportId)
    {
        // ...
    }

    [HttpPost(ReportsSegment)]
    public ActionResult<ReportModel> CreateReport()
    {
        // ...

        var entity = new ReportModel { ReportId = 2 };
        return CreatedAtAction(nameof(GetReport), new { reportId = entity.ReportId }, entity);
    }

    // there are some more actions which belong to the same domain, but are not located
    // under the ReportsSegment. I left them out for brevity.
}

[Route(ApiVersionSegment + "/[controller]/")]
[ApiController]
public class BaseApiController : ControllerBase
{
    protected const string ApiVersionSegment = "v{version:apiVersion}";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue should be fixed by upgrading `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Versioning` to version 4.2 or above. See [this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/aspnet-api-versioning/issues/663) on GitHub. The reason is that before v4.2, API version is not handled as an ambient value during URL generation so it has to be explicitly provided. In other words, before v4.2 you have to write this:

```
[HttpPost(ReportsSegment)]
public ActionResult<ReportModel> CreateReport(ApiVersion apiVersion)
{
    // ...

    var entity = new ReportModel { ReportId = 2 };
    return CreatedAtAction(nameof(GetReport), new { reportId = entity.ReportId, version = apiVersion.ToString() }, entity);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! After updating `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Versioning` to version 5.0.0, the problem disappeared 